# How do I get the correct (latest) version of React quick documentation in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, documentation, code-completion

Using WebStorm IDE. Quick Documentation (on hover) is showing old documentation for React version 16.8.

Does anyone knows how to get this to show the latest version? Is there a setting I'm missing? `package.json` dependency is 18. ¯l_(ツ)_l¯ ?

[image]

Comment: @LazyOne .. Love that you edited me to use proper english. The irony of my own laziness in writing, juxtaposed with your user name, is not lost on me. Well done and thanks mate!

Comment: Have a look if this thread will be any good for your issue: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4417139236114-Javascript-sourcing-outdated-external-library-invalidate-cache-doesn-t-work-

Comment: Well, I guess the (maybe) answer is to just wait. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/67036

Perhaps an upvote or actual issue would be helpful in getting it rolling.